# forward all mails from one machine to postfix mailserver

Tags: postfix, email-server, exim

I am running some servers which generate some mails because of cron jobs or other problems. At the moment, one of them acts as my mailserver (postfix/dovecot) and accepts mails for "abc.com" and "def.com".

I am now trying to redirect all mails from other servers to one mail account on my procution mailserver:

- ALL (!) mails to any local account of let's say "webserver1.def.com" (running exim4) should go to "system@abc.com"
- mails should be send as e.g. "root@webserver1.dev.com" so I can filter by sender address later

But I have these question (really new to relay and multi-host mail servers):

- How can redirect all local mails (exim4) to one address?
- How can I configure exim4 so it uses an external postfix as smtp?
- How can I allow these servers on my primary mail server to send mails? (ans only to this special account mentioned above)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `manualroute` router to the `exim`'s config:

```
begin routers
fwdall:
  driver          = manualroute
  route_list      = * abc.com
  transport       = remote_smtp
  no_more
```

Sure you have to configure `abc.com` to process mail for `webserver1.def.com`.

Messages will be delivered with their original senders - root@, www@ etc so you can filter them by sender's address/domain.

If you want to catch all the mail in the one mailbox, you can use another router:

```
catch:
  driver          = redirect
  data            = catcher@domain.tld
  pipe_transport  = address_pipe
```

This router should be placed above any other router.

If `webserver1.def.com` is not configured as local_domain for `abc.com` and `abc.com` allow relaying from `webserver1.def.com`, then with first router all messages from `webserver1.def.com` will be submitted via `abc.com`, not directly. You have to be careful as long as you can built a closed loop where all the mesages will be sended from the `webserver1.def.com` to the `abc.com` and back again.